# Проверка поля на ввод IP адреса в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Есть компонент `Input`:

```
import {h} from "preact";
const Input = ({children, ...rest}) => (<input {...rest}>{children}</input>);
export default Input;
```

Делаю все на `Preact`
Есть объект `device`, у которого есть свойства `staIP, staMS, staGW`

```
onIPInput( par, event ) {

}

render({}) {
        const {device, linkState} = this.context;
        const {staIP, staMS, staGW} = device;
    return (
        <div>
            <Input value={staIP} type="text" onChange={this.onIPInput.bind(this, "staIP")}/>
            <Input value={staMS} type="text" onChange={this.onIPInput.bind(this, "staMS")}/>
            <Input value={staGW} type="text" onChange={this.onIPInput.bind(this, "staGW")}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Нужно чтобы в него можно было ввести только IP адрес в формате `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`.
Если поставить `type = text`, то можно ввести чего угодно.

Помогите дописать функцию onIPInput.

Answer (score 2):

Ты должен сам проверять изменение состояния поля внутри компонента `Input` и решать подходят ли новые данные под твое описание(можешь написать [регулярку](https://a-panov.ru/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-ip-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80/))
Для этого лучше использовать метод [`onChange()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Comment: Обновил я топик, помогите функцию написать, что то не выходит ничего...

Comment: а что должно происходить?вы ничего не делаете, когда вызывается функция onChange

Comment: Должно провериться введенное значение и если все хорошо, то onInput={linkState("device.apGW")}, т.е. записаться эти данные в device.apGW (или может есть какой то другой способ обновить значения). Я в onChange() передаю ключ, куда записать. Если неверные данные, то подсказка какая-нибудь.

Comment: Можно на лету проверять, например до 3 цифр, значение 0..255, потом автоматом точка ставится.